# Find the limit of $\frac{1}{n^2(1+x^{2n})}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Could someone please check if I have the correct solution for this please.

I need to find the limit as n tends to infinity of 
$$
     f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n^2(1+x^{2n})}
$$

For $x=0$ we have

$f(0)=1/0$ which is undefined, where do I go from here...

Comment: You claim that $f(0)=\frac10$. What is $f$?

Comment: f(x) = { 1/2 if x=1 and 1 if x∈[0,1)

Comment: How could we have guessed that that's what you meant by $f$? And why do you claim that $f(0)=\frac10$?

Comment: apologies, I am maybe getting confused. I just thought that I would find the limit by taking x=0 first which is how I got 1/0 but maybe this is incorrect.

Comment: If so I can remove that from the question

Comment: You have $f_n(0)=\frac1{n^2}$ and therefore $f(0)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(0)=0$.

Comment: Ok, thank you, is this by squeeze theorem?

Comment: No, it is not. ${}$

Answer (score 2):

$0 \leq f _n(x) \leq \frac 1 {n^{2}}$. By Squeeze Theorem $\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)=0$ for any real number $x$.